# Caching / memorizing async context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, python-asyncio

I am using async context managers to get and process the website (I am just web scraping).

I have two basic methods one, that won't change it yielded values ( Obviously when calling on the same class instance)

1. Download the website and loading it to LXML - _get_page
2. Extract the part that I am interested in - _get_pre_info_section

Those operations are relatively CPU heavy or io heavy, and other methods are using them as a context for further data extraction, so actually I download and parse the base section multiple times instead of one

When I tried to cache the values with decorators that I am usually using i getting an error that they didn't yield

How can I cache/memorize the yielded value?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions, tips, and potential solutions

```
    @asynccontextmanager
    async def _get_page(self):
        global session
        async with session.get(self.url) as page:
            yield lxml.html.document_fromstring(await page.text())

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def _get_pre_info_section(self):
        async with self._get_page() as page:
            yield page.xpath(Model.selectors.pre_info_section)[0]
```

PS. global session it's just aiohttp session

Comment: Why use context managers at all? Unless they do some cleanup, `page = await self._get_page()` is clearer, shorter, and saves you a level of indentation. If you move it outside the class and pass in the URL, you can even decorate it with `functools.lru_cache` to get your cache.

Comment: you're right, i will try to change it to normal function